# How do I prevent data getting added additional times after the page is refreshed?

Tags: django, templates, view, model, refresh

I have the following view that allows a user to add a review for a given product.  After the user submits the form, it adds the data to the database and then goes to /view_reviews.html.  However, when I refresh the page it adds that same review again.  How do I ensure the review only gets added once even if the user happens to refresh the page?

```
def add_review(request, product_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
            reviews = Review.objects.filter(product_id=product_id)
            return render(request,'reserve/templates/view_reviews.html',{'form': form, 'product':product, 'reviews':reviews})
    else:
        form = ReviewForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {'form': form})
    return render_to_response('reserve/templates/create_review.html', variables)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only modify data in a POST, and when the request is successful, you redirect to the page.  This way, if you reload, you're only reloading the page itself, not the POST that changed the data.

So instead of `return render(...)`, you should `return HttpReponseRedirect(...)`.

This also has the advantage that you don't have to duplicate code.  After `form.save()` in your example, you have three lines that are really just a view you already have somewhere else.

Comment: awesome, thanks! I've replaced those lines after form.save() with return HttpResponseRedirect('/products/1/reviews/').  How do incorporate the "product_id" parameter instead of hardcoding 1 in the path?

Comment: Look into the `reverse()` function.